# What/Where generates this CSS code to my Wordpress-page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, inspect-element

I've been trying to modify a free WP-theme (Arcade Basic) to be full width. The element I need to modify is, according to inspect element, this:

.container { max-width: 1170px; }

It shows the source as (index):81 on Inspect Element, which is of course the index file of the page. Though I have no idea where that comes from.

It's probably some JS script of the theme but I went over all those with NotePad++:s search function and I didn't find any trace of that kind of code. The style.css doesn't have it either.

Where could that come from?

Theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/arcade-basic/

Comment: have you tried using `!important`? it'll overwrite the css.

Comment: That did the trick. Put the tag in the style.css .container part. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem... glad to help you! happy coding! =)... you might want to search on `css specificity`...

Comment: Thanks! I'll put that on my reading list. Quite new to any kind of coding so there's a lot of learning to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that solved your problem, for reference, the width is set via media queries in the styles.css file. Specifically the following:

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px; }
  .container:before, .container:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .container:after {
    clear: both; }
  @media (min-width: 769px) {
    .container {
      width: 760px; } }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      width: 980px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
      width: 1180px; } }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will save this for future reference. Yesterday I only changed the desktop-size so those other sizes will need to be changed as well.